# How can I whitelist my facebook app & domain?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, message

It looks like there's no way around the recipient limit for messages composed via the send dialog other than being whitelisted on facebook.

I don't want to advertise on facebook, so I'm not sure if the PMD Group might be the solution https://developers.facebook.com/preferredmarketingdevelopers/ads-api-access/

The app should be able of using the "Invite Friends” functionality for multiple recipients in combination with a custom message. Compare Pinterest https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OSfF.png, eBay etc...

**My question would be: How can I apply for whitelisting? Or is it really necessary to approach someone within the facebook organisation? Is there anyone who can help me out?**

Many thanks in advance, Merry Christmas and Happy Holidays!

Thomas

Comment: Still searching for a way to whitelist my app? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook would be a better place without those invite messages.

That limitation is in place with a reason, think about it. Those invites are supposed to be sent to the people you know are interested, not to your whole friendslist.

Comment: I don't talk about spamming all my friends on facebook but it would be very helpful to select a number of recipients and send one general message to them. At the moment I can select every person on my friendslist but the send dialogue just gives me the first selected person.